# How do I screenshot on my RCA Andriod 4.4.2 10" tablet?

Tags: screenshots

When I want to screenshot something I can't becuase I don't know how.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a screenshot by pressing the <kbd>Volume down</kbd> and <kbd>Power</kbd> buttons at the same time.
This is a default feature since Android 4.0.