# Maven Pro Screenshot

Tags: screenshots

How do I take a *screenshot* on a *Maven Pro*? I have tried pressing the power button and everything on the button bar. I don't know what to do.

Answer (score -1):

Typically on android screenshot is power + volumn down and hold

This person had the same answer: [How do I screenshot on my RCA Andriod 4.4.2 10" tablet?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/96908/how-do-i-screenshot-on-my-rca-andriod-4-4-2-10-tablet)

Comment: OP said he has _tried power button and  every-other button_

Comment: I was unsure what he meant by button bar...

Comment: Also, he never mentioned pressing and holding, which makes a world of difference.